# MPFB2 Human Export to Sketchup

Tags: export, texture-baking

I have created a character using MPFB2 and now I need to export it to something Sketchup can use (Collada). Unfortunately, the textures aren't coming with it. I have watched countless videos, but haven't found a solution. I tried to bake the textures, but when I join the pieces (CNRL+J), I get this extra geometry that shows up. It's supposed to be a Male-Asian. If someone can give me a step-by-step, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm using Blender 4.0. Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Really? A question with an answer 7 years old is a duplicate?

Comment: Have you tried packing the materials?

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Is that the same as "Pack Resources" under External Data?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, miswording on my part.

Comment: I tried that. Same results.